# How to pass live data to PyQT table and update TableView

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I am working on building a tab for an existing GUI utility using PyQT5 that will display live data in the form of various tables that receive this updated data from the main window to the tab. I am able to create an initial qabstracttablemodel and display it in the tab successfully, as well as link the signal to the tab using my new data function at the frequency I need. This new_data function updates the data for each tab automatically and keeps it in the function as local 1D arrays.

What I would like to be able to implement now is:

1. A method of passing local variables in new_data to the table model every time it is updated.
2. A function that will automatically update the table view with the new values for the temperature and power arrays every time it comes in, either using signals and emit or the dataChanged built-in function.

I'm sure it's fairly simple, but I can't find an example of this exact method within the tab structure. I also don't have the experience to know exactly how to connect the signals properly or implement what I want.

```
class SummaryTableTab(QMainWindow):

    _update_data = Signal(dict)
    _new_data = Signal(list)

    data = [[None]*2]*2

    temperatures = [None]*NUM_TEMPS
    powers = [None]*NUM_POWERS

    def __init__(self):
    
        super().__init__(title='Tables', parent=parent)
    
        layout = ULayout(spacing=4, margins=8)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        ql_data = self.data
        ql_widg = ql_Widget(ql_data)
    
        layout.addWidget(ql_widg)
    
    def new_data(self, data):
    
        temperatures = data['Temperatures'] 
        for i in range(0, len(temperatures)):
            self.temperatures[i] = temperatures[i]
    
        powers = data['Powers']
        for i in range(0,len(powers)):
            self.powers[i] = powers[i] 
        
        self.data = [self.temperatures, self.powers]
    
        self._update_data.emit({
            'temps': self.temperatures,
            'powers': self.powers,
        })
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and remove all unnecessary parts (imports).

Comment: Edited down to be more clear on what I'm struggling with. I can't provide the function that calls new_data in the main window, but I don't think it's relevant. Any recommendations or resources would be much appreciated.

Comment: To update the data in the model, you need to connect the `_update_data` signal of your main window to a suitable method in your `QAbstractTableModel` subclass. Any changes in the model should be automatically reflected in the view provided you emit the `dataChanged` signal when changing the data of existing items and call `beginInsertRows` / `endInsertRows` and/or `beginRemoveRows` / `endRemoveRows` when adding or removing rows. How this is done depends on what your model class looks like.